# error for size 2 list in merge K sorted List

Tags: c++, sorting, vector, linked-list, stl

I am solving a problem on InterviewBit (Link) : https://www.interviewbit.com/problems/merge-k-sorted-lists/
I have to merge k sorted linked lists and return it as one sorted list.
This is my solution:

```
 * Definition for singly-linked list.
 * struct ListNode {
 *     int val;
 *     ListNode *next;
 *     ListNode(int x) : val(x), next(NULL) {}
 * };
 */
bool is(const ListNode& x, const ListNode& y) { return x.val < y.val; }
ListNode* Solution::mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*> &A) {
    vector<ListNode> m;
    for(int i=0;i<A.size();i++){
        while(A[i]!=NULL){
            m.push_back(*A[i]);
            A[i]=A[i]->next;
        }
    }
    sort(m.begin(),m.end(),is);
    ListNode* k =&m[0];
    for(int i=0;i<m.size()-1;i++){
        m[i].next=&m[i+1];
    }
    m[m.size()-1].next=NULL;
    return k;


}
```

You can copy the code and check with any custom input , it works but returns wrong list when only linked list of size 2 are supplied eg. (1->2) or eg.(1->2 and 3->4) it returns 0->2 and 0->2->3->4 respectively .
(I know this has a bad time complexity )

Comment: Well the algorithm is just wrong. You seem to be assuming that all the lists in `A` have a length of one. However, what's your actual question? There doesn't seem to be one above.

Comment: *It works but returns the wrong list* I think that means it doesn't work. What you need to do is remove the nodes from `A` one at a time (and in the right order) and put them on a new list.

Comment: how I am assuming it ? I tried custom input (1->2->3 , 2->5->6->7, 4->6->9) it returned 1->2->2->3->4->5->6->6->7->9

Comment: OK my apologies, I misread the code.

Comment: What you are basically doing, it combining all the nodes into one list and then sorting it. That's not what you are supposed to be doing. It completely misses the point. And there's still no question.

Comment: I know that it does not take advantage of the already sorted list  thats why I wrote at the last 'I know this has a bad time complexity ' I am more concerned that why does it not give correct result for input size of 2 as stated in the question

Comment: All the lists in `A` are sorted, so the lowest node is is one of the nodes at the head of one of the lists in `A`. Find that node, remove it from `A`, add to your new sorted list. Then repeat. Until all the lists in `A` are empty.

Comment: I know that solution , all I want to know is why is the given algo not correct

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with your code is that the list you are returning consists of pointers to nodes which have been destroyed. So your code has undefined behaviour.

```
ListNode* Solution::mergeKLists(vector<ListNode*> &A) {
    vector<ListNode> m; // this vector contains the nodes of your merged list
    ...
    ListNode* k = &m[0]; // here you take a pointer to the content of m
    ...
        m[i].next = &m[i+1]; // here you make another pointer to the contents of m
    ...
    return k; // here you return that pointer
} // but here m is destroyed
```

So the net result is that you return a pointer to a vector which has been destroyed when the function exits. Any subsequent use of that pointer is undefined behaviour.

Comment: I am not returning pointer to a vector but pointer to a ListNode like a head pointer , it is never destroyed .k stores the address of the 1st node and in the for loop I am updating the next pointer of every node

Comment: The `ListNode` is in a vector `m`, and the vector `m` is local to the function, and you are returning a pointer to `m` contents. But if you don't want to believe me, it's your call.

Comment: That might be the reason then why is it working for all the other cases

Comment: Undefined behaviour (which is what you have) means things are unpredictable.

Comment: I'm not claiming you are returning pointer a vector but a pointer to the vectors contents, `m[0]` specifically. And of course all your next pointers are also pointing at `m` contents. So all those pointers become invalid as soon as `m` is destroyed, which happens when you exit the function.

Comment: So how should I return the pointer ? should I make a temporary ListNode inside the for loop and then assign the ListNode pointer to it and subsequently next nodes

Comment: Well if you are doing this properly, your merged list should reuse the nodes that are in `A`, so at the end of the function `A` just has empty lists because all the nodes have been *moved* onto the new list.

Comment: I suppose you could change `m` to be `vector<ListNode*> m;` and pop nodes off `A[i]` as you push them onto `m`.

Comment: The other choice would be to allocate new ListNodes (with `new`) which would be even less efficient that what you have currently.

Comment: ListNode* k =new ListNode(m[0]);
    ListNode* temp=k;
    for(int i=1;i<m.size();i++){
        temp->next= new ListNode(m[i]);
        temp=temp->next;
    }
    temp->next=NULL;
  
    return k;